# Select part of a string in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a `string` in one column like this

```
India_Project1_BA_Protex_123

Japan_ProQ_CXR_Tbxc_3456
```

I need to select `Project1_BA` or `ProQ_CXR` like this in `mySQL`

Answer (score 16):

There are two functions for extracting some part of string, they are `SUBSTRING` & `SPLITSTRING` but `SUBSTRING` can not be used in this case and `SPLITSTRING` is not present in `MySql`. So you have to write your own function:

**MySQL does not include a function to split a string. However, it’s very easy to create your own function.**

> **Create function syntax**
>
> A **[user-defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)** is a way to extend MySQL with a new
>   function that works like a native MySQL function.
>
> ```
> CREATE [AGGREGATE] FUNCTION function_name
> RETURNS {STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL}
> ```
>
> To create a function, you must have the INSERT privilege for the
>    database.
>
> **Split strings**
>
> The following example function takes 3 parameters, performs an
>   operation using an SQL function, and returns the result.
>
> Function
>
> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
>   x VARCHAR(255),
>   delim VARCHAR(12),
>   pos INT
> )
> RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
> RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
>        LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
>        delim, '');
> ```
>
> **Usage**
>
> ```
> SELECT SPLIT_STR(string, delimiter, position)
> ```
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> SELECT SPLIT_STR('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', '_', 2) as second;
> SELECT SPLIT_STR('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', '_', 3) as third;
>
> +------------++-------+
> | second     || third |
> +------------++-------+
> | Project1   || BA    |
> +------------++-------+
> | ProQ       || CXR   |
> +------------++-------+
> ```

Now you can **concatenate the two results**. to get your final result.

**Full tutorial here: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Got the solution. I used this query  Select CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', '_', 2),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', '_', 2 -1)) + 1),
       '_', ''), '_' , REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', '_', 3),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', '_', 3 -1)) + 1),
       '_', ''))

Comment: @Gulrej Please do accept the answers if they helped... Thanks.

Comment: I changed the `SPLIT_STR` function slightly as it broke for my case using multi-byte characters, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40580413/4852737

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE colum LIKE '%Project1_BA%' OR column LIKE '%ProQ_CXR%'
```

Comment: I have tried like this Select SUBSTRING_INDEX('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', "_", 2) but it is giving me first two part as 'India_Project1' but I want 2nd and 3rd part as 'Project1_BA'

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: They work for ORACLE

I wrote the following queries and they seem to work...

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR( (SELECT SUBSTR('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123',      
INSTR('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', '_')+1, instr('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123',    
'_', 1,2)) AS output
FROM DUAL),1, INSTR((SELECT SUBSTR('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123',   
INSTR('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', '_')+1, instr('India_Project1_BA_Protex_123', 
'_', 1,2)) AS output
FROM DUAL),'_',1,2)-1) FROM DUAL

SELECT 
SUBSTR( (SELECT SUBSTR('Japan_ProQ_CXR_Tbxc_3456', INSTR('Japan_ProQ_CXR_Tbxc_3456',   
'_')+1, instr('Japan_ProQ_CXR_Tbxc_3456', '_', 1,2)) AS output
FROM DUAL),1, INSTR((SELECT SUBSTR('Japan_ProQ_CXR_Tbxc_3456', 
INSTR('Japan_ProQ_CXR_Tbxc_3456', '_')+1, instr('Japan_ProQ_CXR_Tbxc_3456', '_', 1,2)) 
AS output
FROM DUAL),'_',1,2)-1) FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Have you checked it? If it works?? Its giving me error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'instr'

Comment: sorry I din't see that it was for mysql...I tested the above for Oracle and they work..

Comment: you should update your answer and mention it works for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [AlphaMale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10476930/4852737) (*Do I propose code change edit, not sure SO etiquette here?*), I changed the `SPLIT_STR` udf slightly as it breaks for multi-byte characters:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       /* use CHAR_LENGTH instead of LENGTH */
       CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Example:

```
select split_str("Håkansson[!!]Maria", "[!!]", 2) as test;

+------------+
| test       |
+------------+
| Maria      |
+------------+
```