# Find and select part of a string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a description field like:

```
Item
-----
37A38/PE10
520-37Art/PE9
5674/PE01
```

And i just want to select the part before /PE like this:

```
37A38
520-37Art
5674
```

Comment: `select left(item,charindex('/',item))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select part of a string in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476769/select-part-of-a-string-in-mysql)

Comment: mysql or sqlserver ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL

```
select substring(item,1,locate('/PE',item)-1) from table
```

SQL Server

```
select substring(item,1,charindex('/PE',item)-1) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you can use the below code:

```
SELECT LEFT(Item, CHARINDEX('/PE',Item)-1) from table WHERE Item LIKE '%/PE%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `left` and `charindex` for your query,like:-

```
     select left(item,charindex('/',item)) as Item
     from table_name
```